# Inverse transformation of arctan2

Tags: trigonometry, python

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394706/inverse-of-math-atan2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411484/is-there-a-way-to-reverse-the-effect-of-atan2) I'm trying to recover the original 2D field after the `arctan2` operation.

Here's a MWE in python:

```
import numpy as np
theta = np.random.uniform(low=-3*np.pi, high=3*np.pi, size=400)
theta = theta.reshape(20,20)

y     = np.sin(theta)
x     = np.cos(theta)

phi = np.arctan2(y, x)

# theta = f(phi)?
```

how to find `f`? Thanks.

Comment: $\theta$ and $\varphi$ are equal modulo $2\pi$, and $\varphi$ is always in $(-\pi,\pi]$. Therefore, $\varphi$ is the unique angle in $(-\pi,\pi]$ such that $\cos\theta=\cos\varphi$ and $\sin\theta=\sin\varphi$.

Comment: What @Jean-Claude said. There is no such $f$. Your thetas could be anything, but the phis are restricted to $(-\pi,\pi]$. You cannot recover the lost information. FWIW, here's a [Sage plot](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw9jE0OwiAQhfecYpbQYNOoW05iTENqlUlgmACNpaeXSHT33vd-MHBMBWgLXMFmIBaiuLVYME2PydIjhnEjfMYUpI9vc7oMLWDU4PDlzN9lPFZznSYlat9mJPm9UmLvZIn5R9hhZzYtxdJZVg27Eh5zmdnHIm_DgdzbGlpb3dUHcAU4ug==&lang=sage) of phi vs theta.

Comment: To the close voters: this *isn't* exactly a coding question. The code is merely intended to illustrate a *mathematical* question.

Comment: BTW, your MWE isn't minimal. ;) There's no need to use a 2D array, the same problem arises in the 1D case. And we really don't need the theta angles to be random, either.

Comment: By the way, if the variation of theta is smooth enough, there *is* a way to recover theta if only phi is known: shift the angle whenever the jump is too large. That's what is done by MATLAB's [unwrap](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html) function.

Comment: thanks all. this makes sense. I perhaps should add, that this is a geophysical application and theta should be smooth - though the numpy equivalent of unwrap doesn't correctly recover.

Comment: one more thing is that I should be a little clearer. In the actual application, I have $\theta$ and then I have another variable, call it $\varphi$ in (-$\pi, pi$]. I need to sum $\theta$ and $\varphi$ ... perhaps the transformation from $\theta$ to $\phi$ (and the subsequent impossible $f$) is not necessary prior to summation?